# how to handle categorical data that has two or more columns with unique values?

Tags: machine-learning, regression, categorical-data, one-hot-encoding, categorical-encoding

```
df = pd.DataFrame([
['Africa', 'Egypt', 0, 0,155490,1,0.115],
['Africa', 'Kenya', 78182, 7,291210,1,0.45],
['Asia Pacific (excludes Greater China)', 'India', 667657, 1,0,-0.650],
['Asia Pacific (excludes Greater China)', 'Vietnam', 0, 0,0,0,0.005]
])
df.columns = ['Subregion', 'Market', 'Q4 2017', 'Rank_2017','Q4 2018','Rank_2018','year on Year Growth']
```

I just made up the data in actuality there are much more columns and rows
but I Want to know how can I encode these Subregion and Market columns using one-hot encoding or any other way or method or library or work around anything that would do

Comment: Maybe this can help you : https://datascience.stackexchange.com/a/79575/101580

Comment: What is the objective? Maybe, in some cases, it is not categories but rather labels.

Comment: so my objective was to encode these columns using one hot encoding so I tried and did it but it gave me a 1D array  that was not acceptable by the regression to train itself had it been a single column these would have been really easy but here we have 2 column that has categorical data and m not able to perform the learning on these datasets

Comment: It's normal that the one-hot encoding (OHE) gives you an array of features, this is exactly how OHE works. One must **concatenate** these features to the other features in order to provide a one-dimension array of features for every instance. Also don't forget to use `@somebody` when you want to reply to a comment, otherwise the other person is not notified.

Answer (score -1):

it totally depends upon how many unique values does your categorical column has

if your categorical column has :

-> more number of unique values and no ranking  then you should not prefer one hot encoding has it increases the number of columns

-> only few( considering 2 or 3 unique values) consider nominal coding

-> if it has any ordering or ranking then refer ordinal encoding technique

-> target ordinal encoding technique totally depends upon the usecase , so generally avoid it